# Three.js is not correctly loading the object material from .mlt file

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have been trying to load an .obj file with .mlt file([Download Link](https://poly.google.com/view/bTcqWpYqeeM)) in Three.js.

First I have tried to load using **THREE.MTLLoader** and **THREE.OBJLoader** and it was not even loading the object file then I have used the **THREE.OBJLoader2**.

Now the object is loaded but there is no material on it(*screenshot attached*).

[image: Canvas View]
[image: Debugging Window]

The code that I have tried so far.

```
function load_object(scene, url) {
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
   mtlLoader.load('../models/car1/car_02.mtl', function (materials) {
   materials.preload();
   var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader2();
   objLoader.setMaterials(materials.materials);
   objLoader.load('../models/car1/car_02.obj', function (event) {
        var object = event.detail.loaderRootNode;
        scene.add(object);
    }, null, null, null, false);
});
```

}

Comment: I have tried to load your model, and I am also getting the model loaded without texture or color. There is no texture in the zip file downloaded from the URL you have provided. I was also able to load the file using `THREE.OBJLoader`. I think the problem is with your mtl file.

Comment: OK I'll try to load some other model